# Chunking of corresponding data in java

Tags: java, regex

I am new in java I want to chunk string which is present in arraylist.
    For Example : My String ="I am going to Department of agriculture science near to my house" then i want to chunk Department-of-agriculture-science which i added in arraylist in my code

Another Example like "You can use either Iterator or ListIterator for traversing on Java ArrayList" From my code it will give problem something is wrong. but i want output as "You can use either Iterator or ListIterator-for-traversing-on-Java-ArrayList. "ListIterator for traversing" and "traversing on Java ArrayList" is already in arraylist.

I want to chunk token only which i added in list like "Department of ayurveda" "ListIterator for traversing". if my string is "You can use either Iterator or ListIterator for traversing on Java ArrayList" then output should be "You can use either Iterator or ListIterator-for-traversing-on-Java-ArrayList"

My Code :

```
String input = "You can use either Iterator or ListIterator for traversing on Java ArrayList";
    ArrayList<String> alPatterns = new ArrayList<String>();
    alPatterns.add("Department of ayurveda");
    alPatterns.add("science");
    alPatterns.add("ListIterator for traversing");
    alPatterns.add("for traversing on Java ArrayList");
    int NoOfRecords = alPatterns.size();
    int counter = 0;

    final int flags = Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE;
    Iterator it = alPatterns.iterator();

    while (counter++ < NoOfRecords) {
        try {
            String sPat = (String) it.next();
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(sPat, flags);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

            OUTER: while (m.find()) {

                String sMatchFound = m.group();
                String newstring = sMatchFound.replaceAll(" ", "-");
                 input = input.replaceAll(sMatchFound, newstring);
                continue OUTER;
            }

            System.out.println(input);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand a thing about what you want. You want to replace all spaces by -? If not, which spaces to replace?

Comment: @m0skit0 only which i added in list like "Department of ayurveda" "ListIterator for traversing".
if my string is "You can use either Iterator or ListIterator for traversing on Java ArrayList" then output should be "You can use either Iterator or ListIterator-for-traversing-on-Java-ArrayList"

Comment: Ok that's more clear, I suggest you add this clarification in your question.

Comment: @m0skit0 can you suggest some solution?

Comment: Your problem is that you can never know if before/after current match you have another match. This isn't obvious to me how to solve and I don't have time now to further think about it, so sorry.

Comment: @user3201583 if your input is `I am going to Department of ayurveda clinic science` should the output become `I am going to Department-of-ayurveda-clinic science`?

Comment: @Crazenezz please check my code i have edited properly so that youc can understand .now my problem is if my input is "You can use either Iterator or ListIterator for traversing on Java ArrayList"

Then My out put should be "You can use either Iterator or ListIterator-for-traversing-on-Java-ArrayList."
It will hyphanate only the token which i added in list